Ubuntu upgrade something has gone wrong
Ubuntu upgrade has an Oh no! Something has gone wrong error message. This is showing after I click the upgrade Ubuntu option.


Please - give us some details. We don’t know anything about your hardware or what os you’re upgrading from or to - or how you’re trying to upgrade.

This is a common problem people are experiencing while upgrading to 24.04. If that is how you encountered this error, I suggest flashing ubuntu 24.04 in a USB drive and fresh install it. You can use the live session to backup your data in the home folder into another partition

This question is similar to: Fresh install of Ubuntu Desktop 24.04 crashes right before language selection - White screen of death - "Something has gone wrong". If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
